# When we should use NOT ENFORCED with foreign key constraint in DB2?

Tags: db2

The IBM DB2 documentation says:

> To improve the performance of queries, you can add informational
>   constraints to your tables.

And there is this `NOT ENFORCED` option we can provide:

```
ALTER TABLE <name> <constraint attributes> NOT ENFORCED
```

The explanation is fairly simple:

> NOT ENFORCED should only be specified if the table data is
>   independently known to conform to the constraint. Query results might
>   be unpredictable if the data does not actually conform to the
>   constraint.

From what I understood - if I have let's say a `foreign key`, in a table, declared as `NOT ENFORCED` that's absolutely the same as not having it at all.

**But then what are the real use cases for it and when this option should be used?**
(what is the difference between having NOT ENFORCED constraint vs not having it at all)

Answer (score 2):

The so-called [Information Constraints](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/c0023324.html) can be used to improve performance. This is done by adding insights to the database. Without the informational constraint Db2 would not know about the relationship between the two tables and related columns. Now, the SQL query compiler and optimizer can exploit the fact and optimize query execution.

As a consequence, the informational constraint should only be applied when indeed the data is constraint in the specified ways. Db2 does not enforce it, the user (you) is guaranteeing that data property. Hence, when it is not true, query results could be wrong because Db2 assume that the relationships are present.

Comment: If I can guarantee data consistency why would I add such constraint at all? If I know data are correct I don't provide any constraint hence I get better performance.

Comment: As stated above, you would add it to tell Db2 about the relationship and that it could be used for optimization. RI constraints tell something about cardinalities.

Comment: If you're doing high volume inserts, as part of something like an ETL process, it might be faster to load the data and tell the DB that the constraint has been independently checked, than it is to re-scan a bunch of data.

Comment: An example for using an unenforced & untrusted constraint may be a scenario where there is no existing constraints, and they're "enforced" by an external application. The constraint gives you the metadata of how things may look in a perfect world, without causing the external application folks to complain that inserts are failing (because a bug is generating duplicate data).